# Sort and then multiply each item in array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a problem with this type of function.

This function requires an array of numbers as a parameter, which must be sorted and then each element of the array must be multiplied * 3.

I use sort() method for sorting the array and map() method for multiply each element of the array.

I don't know what's wrong because the function return a sorted array, but the elements in array are not multiplied * 3.

Here is the code, hoping someone can help me:

```
calibrate(inputArray) {
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        inputArray.sort((a, b) => a - b)
        inputArray.map(function(x) { 
            return x * 3; 
        });
        this.calibrationSequence.push(inputArray[i]);
    }
    return this.calibrationSequence;
}
```

Comment: `map` returns a new array, it doesn't modify the original array.

Comment: is `inputArray` a one dimensional array? What exactly is the goal of `calibrationSequence`? `sort` and `map` are functions that iterate through the whole array. I am not sure why you would need the for loop?

Comment: You have the sort and map inside a for loop, so you’re sorting and multiply each item by 3 *for every single item in the array*. So if you have an array of length 10, you’re sorting and multiplying it 10 times.

Comment: Then? Can you recommend a way to make the function work better? @Barmar

Comment: Just assign the result back to the variable.

Comment: How else to you use the returned value of functions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it's not necesary to iterate with for loop, the map method iterates the array and applies a function.

```js
function calibrate(inputArray) {
    var sortedArray = inputArray.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    var calibrationSequence = sortedArray.map(x => x * 3);
    return calibrationSequence;
}

console.log(calibrate([1,4,3,5,2]));    //Output: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the returned array after the multiplication

```js
   inputArray = [3,2,1]
   inputArray.sort((a, b) => a - b)
   inputArray = inputArray.map(function(x) { 
    return x * 3; 
   });        
   console.log(inputArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

map() doesn't update the original array, it's creating a new one instead.

to make it short you can do something like this:

```
function calibrate(inputArray) {

  return inputArray.sort((a, b) => a - b)
                   .map(function(x) { 
                        return x * 3; 
                   });

}
```